# Cython installation warning

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to install Cython into python3.3 using pip3.3 on elementary OS linux and a warning(which is posted below) is what unexpectedly pops up.

```
pip3.3 install Cython
Downloading/unpacking Cython
  Downloading Cython-0.20.1.tar.gz (2.6MB): 2.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_tej/Cython/setup.py) egg_info for package Cython
    /usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/dist.py:258: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:     'entry_points'
  warnings.warn(msg)
    /usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/dist.py:258: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/dist.py:258: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'

  warnings.warn(msg)

/usr/lib/python3.3/distutils/dist.py:258: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'

  warnings.warn(msg)

usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

   or: -c --help-commands

   or: -c cmd --help



error: invalid command 'egg_info'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_tej/Cython
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpshew0_
```

Please I would need your help on this since it is a barrier to installing other applications and frameworks to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo pip3 install -U  setuptools
```

setuptools and distribute have been merged, [Setuptools/Distribute Merge](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/merge-faq.html)